# Make jQuery do the click function

Tags: php, jquery, function, click

I don't know which tag or event to use. But I would like some way to make jQuery do a click function or "click" a link when the page is loaded. The script is getting a specific data from the URL. If the url sais: www.domain.com/index.php?a=1&b=1234 then I would like something like this in the beginning:

> <?php
> $a = $_GET['a'];
> $b = $_GET['b'];
> if ($a == '1') 
> {
> //echo jQuery script that automatically clicks the <a> tag
> }
> ?>

and then the HTML script is like this:

> <a href="page2.php/<? echo $b; ?>">jQuery Click</a>

Please help me

Comment: Why not just redirect to that page?

Comment: If you really want to simulate a click with jQuery, look at this: http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/Events/Mouse

Comment: @Brad beacause the page is working normally as a website and I only want to o a specific click if $a == '1'.. The thing is, that the page is not refreshing.. it is directed into a div.. which means that the div will only be filled with the given content if $a == '1'.

Comment: @Philip, This is not a good way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

Comment: Or just the `.click` method with no arguments.

Comment: That runs event handlers, not clicking as OP is asking. http://jsfiddle.net/jcRMB/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#YOUR_ID').click();
```

or

```
$('a#YOUR_ID').trigger('click');
```

or

```
$('a.YOUR_CLASS').click();
```

or using `href`

```
$('a[href^="page2.php"]').click();
```

First one is preferred. You should make selector with your ID of CLASS belongs to that `a`.

**NOTE:**  `a[href="page2.php"]` means `a` tag which `href` beginning exactly with `page2.php`

If none of above works then try:

```
window.location = document.location.hostname + '/' + $('a[href^="page2.php"]').attr('href');
```

Two open a popup try this:

```
var urlToOpen = document.location.hostname + '/' + $('a[href^="page2.php"]').attr('href');

window.open (urlToOpen,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

Detail about [**window.open()**](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: erm what if there was multiple 'a' s?

Comment: the .click event doesn't work and neither does the .trigger event.

Answer (score 0):

Do this  :

```
$("a[href='page2.php']").click();
```

or prefferably use an ID

```
$("a#myID").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information in the jQuery documentation or perhaps a tutorial at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

To answer your specific question, I believe you are looking for something similar to:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#autoclick').click();
});
```

My recommendation would be to apply an id in the corresponding html:

`<a id="autoclick" href="/somewhere-else">This is a link</a>`

Hope that helps you get started.

Note: The click() has this as a specific shortcut for trigger("click") since v1.0.  Ref: [jQuery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)